# format message on angular-moment moment.js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, momentjs

How would i change the ago message using [`angular-moment`](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment). i use this `angular-moment` library to show time ago message.

```
 <span am-time-ago="created_at"></span>
```

It shows messages like "a few seconds ago".

How can we make this message shorter?  Can we remove `ago` from this message?
 So the message would be like:
 1sec , 1min, 12min , 1hour, 12hours, 2years etc.

I tried to do this using:

```
moment.lang('en', {
relativeTime : {
    future: "in %s",
    past:   "%s ago",
    s:  "sec",
    m:  "1m",
    mm: "%m",
    h:  "1h",
    hh: "%h",
    d:  "1d",
    dd: "%dd",
    M:  "1m",
    MM: "%dm",
    y:  "1y",
    yy: "%dy"
}
});
```

placed this thing in angular `app.js` after module.  It worked well for 1 sec, 1 min, 1 hr, etc..
but it shows `%` in place of absolute time. like `%min`, instead of `12min`.

Any suggestion?

Comment: The moment docs cover this exact scenario, when using `.fromNow`, add a parameter to forgive the suffix, ex: `moment().fromNow(true)` omits the "ago" portion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`angular-moment` provides `amTimeAgoConfig`, for specifying whether or not `ago` should be displayed:

```
app.constant('amTimeAgoConfig', {
  withoutSuffix: true
});
```

`moment.js` allows us to define functions to format [`relativeTime`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time/), and these seem to work with `angular-moment`.  In this example, I defined functions for seconds and minutes:

```
moment.lang('en', {
  relativeTime: {
    future: "in %s",
    past: "%s ago",
    s: function(number, withoutSuffix, key, isFuture) {
      return number + ' sec';
    },
    m: "1m",
    mm: function(number, withoutSuffix, key, isFuture) {
      return number + 'm';
    }
  }
});
```

If you want to try the code, [here it is on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tshEpte4ug2MK1cc0cPN?p=preview).